Looker Studio: Filter one table based on the field of the selected item on another table
I have one set of data and it is structured like this in two separate  columns.
Item    - Category

Apple - Fruit
Banana    - Fruit
Cat   - Animal
Dog   - Animal
Elephant  - Animal
Fence - Yard
Garden    - Yard

I would like to show this table to the user. I want the user to be able to select one of the items from the list. When they select an item, a second table to be filtered based on Category.
Example: User selects Apple, the other table should be filtered to only show all and only Fruits (Apple and Banana)
Tried using Parameters, cross filters and data blends but does not seem to be working.
Tried using Parameters, cross filters and data blends but does not seem to be working.

I think this will work for you
If you have exactly the same name Field ID on both tables the filter should work. 
You get the same Field ID either by having exactly the same data type and Field Name on both tables or by adding a field eg =item and type in the same Field IDs they should link
